# Помогите построить запрос

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица **table** с полями **id**, **refpost**, **type** и **comment**. Тип поля **comment** TEXT.
Необходимо получит строки, где refpost у которой type='A' или type='D', который встречается в поле comment.
Пробовал так:

```
SELECT id, refpost, type, comment
    FROM table
    WHERE comment
    LIKE 
        (
        SELECT refpost
            FROM table
            WHERE type='A'
            OR type='D'
        )
```

Выдает сообщение об ошибке. 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Поясните эту фразу `где refpost у которой type='A' или type='D'`

Comment: `SELECT id, refpost, type, comment FROM table WHERE comment LIKE %refpost% AND (type='A' OR type='D');` не так?

Comment: Мне нужны строки таблицы, где в `comment` встречаются `refpost` у которого `type` равно `A` или `B`.

Comment: ArchDemon Ваш код ругается на синтаксическую ошибку.